# Angular Library Host Version Error with Component Styles

Tags: angular, components, styles, angular-library

I generated my first Angular library via the CLI in Angular 13 (v13.1.0) that mainly used services, and that was no problem.  Now I created another one the same way, a Loader Module, but I intend to use a component.  When it gets generated, it only shows component.ts and component.spec.ts files.  When I build the library, everything works as intended, no problems.  But I need to apply styles to the component.  So I have tried 3 different ways:

- Importing a .css file in styleUrls
- Importing a .scss file in styleUrls
- Adding inline styles

Each time I try to build the library, I get the following error:

**Compiling with Angular sources in Ivy partial compilation mode.
X [ERROR] Cannot start service: Host version "0.14.11" does not match binary version "0.14.2**

The only time it completely works is if I don't include any styles.  I don't know if I'm missing something in my project to make this work, if I need to update something, or what.  The configurations include:

```
// tsconfig.lib.json
{
  "extends": "../../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../../out-tsc/lib",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "types": [],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2018"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}

// tsconfig.lib.prod.json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.lib.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declarationMap": false
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "compilationMode": "partial"
  }
}

// library package.json
{
  "name": "loader",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^13.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^13.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.3.0"
  }
}

// angular.json for library
"loader": {
  "projectType": "library",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "style": "scss"
    }
  },
  "root": "projects/loader",
  "sourceRoot": "projects/loader/src",
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:ng-packagr",
      "options": {
        "project": "projects/loader/ng-package.json"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "tsConfig": "projects/loader/tsconfig.lib.prod.json"
        },
        "development": {
          "tsConfig": "projects/loader/tsconfig.lib.json"
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "production"
    },
    "test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "main": "projects/loader/src/test.ts",
        "tsConfig": "projects/loader/tsconfig.spec.json",
        "karmaConfig": "projects/loader/karma.conf.js"
      }
    },
    "lint": {
      "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
      "options": {
        "lintFilePatterns": [
          "projects/loader/**/*.ts",
          "projects/loader/**/*.html"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}

// main tsconfig.ts file
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "loader": [
        "dist/loader/app-loader",
        "dist/loader"
      ]
    },
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

If anybody can help me out here, that will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message after I upgraded the `@angular/cli` and `@angular-devkit/build-angular` from **13.1.2** to **13.1.5**.

Deleting the existing `dist`, `node_modues` and `.angular` folders solved it for me.